# java.util.prefs.Preferences.put() works, but Preferences.nodeExists() always returns false 

Tags: java, preferences

I have some simple code I am using to learn OAuth authentication using the signpost library. I am trying to save the request token, the token secret and the pin as Java preferences, using `java.util.prefs.Preferences`. Putting the data into the preferences works fine (I check that the file is created and the information stored). However, immediatelly after I `put()` the data into the Preferences file, I try to check if the node exists, and I always get `false`.

I also tried just re-running the code, and checking for the node's existence before I try to save the data again, and I still get false.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Here is the code:

```
package com.example;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.prefs.Preferences;

import oauth.signpost.OAuth;
import oauth.signpost.OAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.OAuthProvider;
import oauth.signpost.basic.DefaultOAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.basic.DefaultOAuthProvider;

public class ReadMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        OAuthConsumer consumer = 
        new DefaultOAuthConsumer(
                "??",
                        "??");

        OAuthProvider provider = 
        new DefaultOAuthProvider(
            "https://www.readability.com/api/rest/v1/oauth/request_token/",
                    "https://www.readability.com/api/rest/v1/oauth/access_token/", 
                    "https://www.readability.com/api/rest/v1/oauth/authorize/");

        System.out.println("Fetching request token from Readability...");

        Preferences prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(ReadMain.class);

        final String PREF_TokenSecret    = "com/example/TS";
        final String PREF_RequestToken   = "com/example/RT";
        final String PREF_ReadabilityPin = "com/example/RP";

        boolean exists = 
            prefs.nodeExists( PREF_TokenSecret ) &&
        prefs.nodeExists( PREF_RequestToken ) &&
        prefs.nodeExists( PREF_ReadabilityPin );

        if ( prefs.nodeExists( PREF_TokenSecret ) )
        {
        System.out.println("Token secret exists!");
        }

        if ( prefs.nodeExists( PREF_RequestToken ) )
        {
        System.out.println("Request token exists!");
        }

        if ( prefs.nodeExists( PREF_ReadabilityPin ) )
        {
        System.out.println("Readability pin exists!");
        }

        String pin;

        if ( exists )
        {
        consumer.setTokenWithSecret( 
                prefs.get(PREF_RequestToken,""), 
                prefs.get(PREF_TokenSecret,"") );
            pin = prefs.get(PREF_ReadabilityPin,"");
        }
        else
        {
        // we do not support callbacks, thus pass OOB
        String authUrl = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer, OAuth.OUT_OF_BAND);

        System.out.println( "Request token: " + consumer.getToken() );
        System.out.println( "Token secret: " + consumer.getTokenSecret() );

        prefs.put( PREF_RequestToken, consumer.getToken() );
        prefs.put( PREF_TokenSecret,  consumer.getTokenSecret() );

        System.out.println( "Now visit:\n" + authUrl + "\n... and grant this app authorization" );
        System.out.println( "Enter the PIN code and hit ENTER when you're done:" );

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        pin = br.readLine();

        prefs.put(PREF_ReadabilityPin, pin);

        if ( prefs.nodeExists( PREF_TokenSecret ) )
        {
            System.out.println("Token secret exists!");
        }

        if ( prefs.nodeExists( PREF_RequestToken ) )
        {
            System.out.println("Request token exists!");
        }

        if ( prefs.nodeExists( PREF_ReadabilityPin ) )
        {
            System.out.println("Readability pin exists!");
        }
        }

        System.out.println("Fetching access token from Readability...");
        provider.retrieveAccessToken(consumer, pin);

        System.out.println("Access token: " + consumer.getToken());
        System.out.println("Token secret: " + consumer.getTokenSecret());

        URL url = new URL("https://www.readability.com/api/rest/v1/bookmarks?user=marcusps&archive=1");
        HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        consumer.sign(request);

        System.out.println("Sending request to Readability...");
        request.connect();

        System.out.println("Response: " + request.getResponseCode() + " "
            + request.getResponseMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The opposite operation of `put(..)` is `get(..)`. So:

```
boolean exists = prefs.get(key, null) != null;
```

the `get(..)` method returns the 2nd argument if there is nothing found under the specified key.

the `nodeExists()` is related to the hierarchical structure of preferences, and can be used when you've used `prefs.node(..)` to create a node. But you seem to need a flat structure, so you don't need hierarchies, I think.

Comment: Seems to work, but I don't get why `nodeExists(...)` returns false, even though `get(key, null) != null`.

Comment: @Marus - If we say that a node is similar to a directory, a key-value is like a file. So, if you `put` a file, there is no directory `nodeExist` there, just the file exists `get`.

Comment: +1 to @Ishtar for a perfect explanation of the hierarchical structure of the preferences.

Comment: then what do we do with nodeExists() ?

Comment: @Ahad You can check for existence of directories.